# fit webpage to any browser/screen size

Tags: html, css

I've defined the width and height of all my web page elements in pixels, which lead to huge blank spaces when displayed on larger screens. It's quite time-consuming to redefine everything to percentages. Is there a way to make my current webpages fit to any size screen automatically

Comment: Without some hacky javascript, no. Just change them to percentages if you want the website to have good code.

Comment: Don't look for workarounds. Make the code in the correct way and you will a more mainteneable project.

Answer (score -1):

This gives you a responsive web design to fit any mobile, tablet, and laptop screen.
 ---> [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) gives a better explanation <--
add the meta tag in the

```
<head> in between these lines  </head>
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: This will *break* the site on mobiles as it will tell them to render the site as if it were designed for screens of their size … which it isn't … which is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.